# Get Latest N Documents from Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a standard Solr 3.6 index and am looking to get the latest N documents back (date ascending from indexing them).

This [site](http://phatness.com/2009/11/sorting-by-date-with-solr/) was helpful but not exactly what I'm looking for.

I am looking to do something like this:

```
localhost:8080/solr/select/?q=greekbailout&wt=json; date asc
```

Basically, query whatever with json output and the latest N submitted documents to the index. Anybody run into this before?

Comment: When I use [begin uri] http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?q=greece&wt=json&sort=date asc [end uri] I get an HTTP Status 400 - sort param field can't be found: date. However, in my default 3.6 Schema I have [begin xml tag] <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/> [end xml tag]. However, this does work: [begin uri] q=data:greece; date asc [end uri]. Why is this? Thank you

Comment: thank you all for your help if i could uptick you all more i would

Comment: 3 years later and a greek bailout seems much more likely now....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solr query using date field with N documents returned in results

```
localhost:8080/solr/select/?q=greekbailout&wt=json&sort=date asc&rows=N
```

default schema of solr has a field called timestamp, which stores time at which a particular document is created or modified,  so if your date field doesn't quite store this and this is your requirement, you can use timestamp.. just replace date with timestamp

Answer (score 2):

Use `&sort=date asc` for pure sorting and [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents) for boosting newer documents.

Answer (score 1):

In your Solr URL just apend `&sort=<field>+<asc/desc>`. Also your field should be indexed and not multivalued.
You can also sort on multiple fields.

```
&sort=<field name>+<direction>[,<field name>+<direction>]...
```

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort